# xcodeを7.0にアップグレードしたら、コンパイルに失敗

Tags: xcode, xcode7

不用意にxcodeを7.0にアップグレードしてしまいました。
その結果、ターミナルでfortranを動かそうとすると下のようなエラーが発生し、
コンパイルすることができなくなりました。

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

どのようにすれば解決できるかを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: gfortranを入れ直すことにより、通常通りコンパイルできるようになりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

恐らく依存関係がアップデートにより壊れている可能性があります。
`GFortran`ですよね？
入れ直してみてはいかがでしょうか？

シミュレータなどを使う場合は、
アップデートによりシミュレータの中身のライブラリも消えちゃってるはずなので
シミュレータ内部のライブラリも確認した方が良いと思います。